# Reassign an interface or allow GC to do its work on temporary variables

Tags: variables, go, garbage-collection, variable-assignment, assign

I'm very new to Go and am currently porting a PHP program.

I understand that Go is not a dynamically-typed language and I like that about it. It seems very structured and easy to keep track of everything.

But I've been coming across situations that seem to be a little ... ugly. Is there a better way of performing this sort of process:

```
plyr := builder.matchDetails.plyr[i]
plyrDetails := strings.Split(plyr, ",")
details := map[string]interface{}{
    "position": plyrDetails[0], "id": plyrDetails[1],
    "xStart": plyrDetails[2], "zStart": plyrDetails[3],
}
```

EDIT:

Is there a better way to achieve a map containing the strings from `plyr` than to create two additional variables, to be destroyed straight afterwards? Or is this the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr:

- If possible, choose a different format and let a library do the string parsing/generation for you
- Use `struct`s rather than `map`s for anything you use a few times, for more compiler checks
- The common way of using `encoding/json` accomplishes both of those.

Meanwhile, don't sweat perf too much because you'll probably vastly improve the old app's speed regardless; there's no indication speed of parsing or GC is a problem yet; and the syntactical differences you mentioned in the first rev. of the post don't necessarily actually relate to GC.

---

So, I understand you may be porting piece-for-piece, and that may limit what you can change now.

But if/when you can change things, a *really* clean solution would be to use [the `encoding/json` package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) and a struct: the `json` package will parse input/generate output from structs without any manual string manipulation on your part, and using a struct gives you compile-time checking rather than only the runtime checking you get with a `map`. Lots of Go apps (and others) use JSON to expose their services.

An intermediate step could be to introduce `struct` types for any internal structure you use at least a few times, rather than `map`s, so even without updating the parsing, at least the *internals* of the app get the benefits of compile-time checking. `struct`s are also what things like [the `gorm` object/relational mapper](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) expect to deal with. They *happen* to use less memory than maps, and be quicker (and more concise syntactically) to access, but those aren't even necessarily the most important considerations here.

On the *performance* of what you have now, and particularly whether different syntax would make it faster: don't sweat that, for a bunch of reasons: the port's likely to be faster than the PHP was whatever you do; we don't yet have any indication that parsing or GC is actually slow or your bottleneck; and the syntactical differences you talked about in the first revision of your question may not relate to GC much or at all. More/fewer var names in your code may not correspond to more/fewer heap allocations, 'cause often Go can allocate on the stack, briefly discussed under ['escape analysis' in Dave Cheney's Gocon Tokyo slides](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/07/five-things-that-make-go-fast). And as peterSO said, we seem to be looking at allocations of smallish references, not, say, copying all of the string bytes from the request each time.

Answer (score 2):

Go is NOT PHP. Write Go programs in Go. Write PHP programs in PHP.

> Interface values are represented as a two-word pair giving a pointer
>   to information about the type stored in the interface and a pointer to
>   the associated data. [Go Data Structures:
>   Interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

Reusing Go interface variables to "increase performance" makes no sense.

Comment: I did not mean to say I wanted to use interfaces to increase performance, I simply asked is there a better way to perform the processes I showed above and used an interface as an example